# Read table and output via echo

Tags: php, html-table, echo

In my first piece of code you can see how I build a table with the echo output. Everything works fine.

```
 echo "<form method=\"post\" action=''>";
    echo "<table border=\"1\">";
    foreach($pdo -> query($sqlSpielerNamen) as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td style=\"font-size: 10;\">".$row['Player_ID']."</td>";
        echo "<td style=\"font-size: 10;\">".$row['SpielerName']."</td>";
        echo "<td syle=\"font-size: 10 ;\"><input name='note' type='text' class='textfield' id='note_id' value='$spielID' />";
        echo "<td syle=\"font-size: 10 ;\"><input name='tore' type='text' class='textfield' id='tore_id' value='$spielID' />";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<br><br><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit_eingabemaske\" value=\"Abschicken\">\n";
    echo "</form>";
```

But now, I need a new output from this table after clicking on the submit button.
I need the first field 'Player_ID' and the last two fields 'note' and 'tore'.

At the moment my output looks like this. But I know that this is not the correct solution.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_eingabemaske'])){
$Po = $_POST["tore"];
foreach ($row as $item){
            echo $Po;
}}
```

What I have to do in the second piece of code, that my result will be correct. How can I achieve this? Another problem for my is, how to call the first field 'Player_ID'? The fields 'tore' and 'name' I can get with $POST["tore"]...

Comment: `name='note'` should be `name='note[]'` and likewise for the other input, then iterate over that array and output. Also use single quotes for all your HTML attributes. Ids also should be unique and if the value is the same you don't really need the second input, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of beginners' mistakes here.

**First** of all - you shouldn't use such complex strings with double quotes.

There are more simpler ways:

```
// see, I wrap string in single quotes, 
// and all quotes inside the string are double ones
echo '<form method="post" action="">';
```

Even simpler is to close `?>`:

```
<?php
// code here
?>
<form method="post" action="">
```

**Next**, as you create a lot of fields with same `name`, you will receive only last value of the field with such name. So,

```
<input name='note' type='text' class='textfield' id='note_id' value='11' />
<input name='note' type='text' class='textfield' id='note_id' value='22' />
<input name='note' type='text' class='textfield' id='note_id' value='33' />
```

will give you only `33` on server side. That's why you need to use `[]` notation for `name`:

```
<input name='note' type='text' class='textfield' id='note_id[]' value='11' />
<input name='note' type='text' class='textfield' id='note_id[]' value='22' />
<input name='note' type='text' class='textfield' id='note_id[]' value='33' />
```

In this case your `$_POST['note_id']` will hold **all** values from a form.
Same to `name='tore'`.

**Third**, if you want to pass some hidden value to a server, you can use `input` with type `hidden`, it's not seen on the page but still exists and passes to server:

```
<!-- Again, use [] for getting several values -->
<input type="hidden" name="player_id[]" id="" value="<?=$Player_ID?>" />
```

So, you can rewrite code as:

```
<?php
// Some code here
// close previous opened php-tag
?>
<form method="post" action=''>
<table border="1">
<?php
foreach($pdo -> query($sqlSpielerNamen) as $row){?>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 10;"><?php echo $row['Player_ID']?><input type="hidden" name="player_id[]" value="<?=$row['Player_ID']?>" /></td>
        <td style="font-size: 10;"><?=$row['SpielerName']?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 10 ;"><input name='note[]' type='text' class='textfield' value='<?=$spielID?>' />";
        <td style="font-size: 10 ;"><input name='tore[]' type='text' class='textfield' value='<?=$spielID?>' />";
    </tr>
<?php
}?>
</table>
<br><br><input type="submit" name="submit_eingabemaske" value="Abschicken">
</form>
```

Here `<?=` is a short syntax for `<?php echo`.

On server you can:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_eingabemaske'])){
    print_r($_POST);    // see what you have in post
    foreach ($_POST['player_id'] as $id){
        // do something
    }
}
```

One final warning is for using `id` attribute of `input`.

`id` attribute **must** be unique on the page. You can have same ids, but **all** javascript codes working with these ids will work only with first element, having this id. That's why I removed `id` from output. If you need something in common for all inputs - use classes.

**Update**: from my point of view if you want to generate fileds with `foreach`, you can:

```
// define array of fields' params
$fields = [
    ['name' => 'player_id', 'value' => $row['Player_ID'], 'type' => 'hidden', 'class' => ''],
    ['name' => 'note', 'value' => $spielID, 'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'textfield'],
    ['name' => 'tore', 'value' => $spielID, 'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'textfield'],
];
foreach ($fields as $f) {
    echo '<input name="' . $f['name'] . '[]" type="' . $f['type'] . '" class="' . $f['class'] . '"  value="' . $f['value'] . '" />';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that awesome solution. But I have a last question. In the second piece of code, there is at the moment von field player_id. But how would look the foreach for 3 fields ... player_id, note, tore? I want to echo all three fields in one line

Comment: I advise you to write final result what you want to see and then think how you can move to `foreach` - see what is common with these fields, what is changing. But anyway, I don't think it's a good idea as there're many different items that should be iterated somehow.

Comment: I'm absolut beginner and at the moment I'm try to learn php. I want an output of these three fields. At the moment it is not important for me if this make sense. I want only try something...